# C# Generics typecast List<T> to List< BaseType>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

How can i typecast `List<Car>` to  `List<MyBaseClass>`, In my code instance of List will go as an **object** (program requirement not intentional), by doing this i will retrieve vehicleId..

```
 public Form1()
    {           
        List<Car> lstCar = new List<Car>();
        lstCar.Add(new Car() { Make = "tootay", Model = "camry", VechicleId = 1 });
        lstCar.Add(new Car() { Make = "honda", Model = "civic", VechicleId = 2 });
        VehicleConverter(lstCar);
    }
    public void VehicleConverter(object obj)
    {
      //Want to typecast it to List<MyBaseClass>            
    }        
}

public class MyBaseClass
{        
    public int VechicleId { get; set; }        
}

public class Car:MyBaseClass
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
}

public class Bike : MyBaseClass
{
    public int CC { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't mention if you're using .NET 4.0 or earlier, but if you are using .NET 4.0 then the new co-variance/contra-variance feature for generic interfaces may help you.

You've discovered that you can't cast `List<Car>` as `List<MyBaseClass>`, but with .NET 4.0 you can cast `IEnumerable<Car>` as `IEnumerable<MyBaseClass>`.

You could then call functions that require an `IEnumerable<MyBaseClass>` with your `List<Car>` as the parameter without doing any special conversion or casting code.

For example, this code works in .NET 4.0:

```
List<Car> lstCar = new List<Car>();
lstCar.Add(new Car() { Make = "tootay", Model = "camry", VechicleId = 1 });
lstCar.Add(new Car() { Make = "honda", Model = "civic", VechicleId = 2 });

VehicleConverter(lstCar);

public void VehicleConverter(IEnumerable<MyBaseClass> vehicles)
{
    var found = vehicles.Where(v => v.VechicleId == 123);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible.

Had it been possible, you would be able to write the following:

```
List<Car> carList = new List<Car>();
List<BaseClass> baseList = (List<BaseClass>)carList;
baseList.Add(new Bike());    //I just put a Bike into a List<Car>!
```

Alternatives:

- Declare the list as `List<BaseCLass>`
- Cast to a non-generic `IList` (not recommended)
- Cast to `IEnumerable<BaseClass>`, using .Net 4's covariance
- Pass a typed copy of the list:

  ```
  VehicleConverter(lstCar.ConvertAll(c => (BaseClass)c));
  ```

Comment: He's not trying to cast a car into a bike.  Reread the question.

Comment: Haha, the canonical example :)

Comment: @yoda: So what? This is why his request is impossible.

Comment: @Slaks: I don't see in the question where he's trying to add a bike to a car list either.  The question explicitly states he wants a list of baseclass from his list of cars.

Comment: @yoda: I realize that.  The reason you can't cast `List<Car>` to `List<BaseClass>` is that it would allow this code.

Comment: @yodaj007: SLaks is right. It doesn't matter if the user actually *is* doing that or not. The point is that if the conversion were legal then he *could* do that *and the compiler would have no way of stopping him*. The only place where we can accurately detect that type safety *could* be violated *later* is on the conversion, so the conversion is illegal.

Comment: Gotcha.  I'm following now.  Don't mean to be difficult; I'm just slow.

Answer (score 1):

And the reason why this is not possible is because you could runtime errors like this:

```
var cars = new List<Car>();
var vehicles = (List<MyBaseClass>)cars; // Not possible, but assume it was
vehicles.Add(new Bike());  // Runtime fail because now you are trying to add a bike to a list of cars
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<MyBaseClass> VehicleConverter<T>(List<T> obj)
    where T : MyBaseClass
{
    return obj.Cast<MyBaseClass>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: This will copy the list.  `ConvertAll` would be a little faster.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the "IEnumerable.Cast<T>()" extension method from the System.Linq namespace.

Here is a link to the msdn documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx

Here is an example:

```
public void VehicleConverter(IEnumerable obj)
{
     IEnumerable<MyBaseClass> enumerable = obj.Cast<MyBaseClass>();
     List<MyBaseClass> list = enumerable.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
if (obj is List<Car>)
{
    List<MyBaseClass> c = ((List<Car>)obj).ToList<MyBaseClass>();
}
```

But you would need to do it for each type.  Ideally you should cast before passing to VehicleConverter.

Seems like an odd requirement though and would suggest @yodaj007 option if you are allowed to use that.

Comment: This will also copy the list.

Comment: It may copy the list object itself the contents of the list are still pointers to the original objects that were part of the original list.  So you can still enumerate the vehicles.

Answer (score 0):

Even though i could not convert it to BaseClass, but i achieved my objective of retrieving the vehicleId by Casting & Reflection.

```
    public void VehicleConverter(object obj)
    {

        Type t = obj.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetType();
        IList lstVec = ((IList)obj);
        foreach (var k in lstVec)
        {
            PropertyInfo[] p = k.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (PropertyInfo pi in p)
                if (pi.Name == "VechicleId")
                    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(pi.GetValue(k, null)));
        }
    }
```